# How do we automate the Refreshing of LUIS Dispatcher Model?

Tags: .net, node.js, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

*1. If we can go with Function App in Azure, how do we get the Dispatcher CLI to work in this function? Is there any code to run the NODE JS and install Dispatcher CLI and run the refresh command?*

*2. Will it be possible to use Container in Blob storage?? If so, how do we use NodeJS and Dispatcher CLI and refresh?*

*I don't want to go with VM, Is there any APP SERVICE in Azure which can achieve this Task?*

The refreshing of dispatcher using `dispatch refresh` command can be used with NodeJS and installing Dispatcher module in windows. For more info, please refer the source : [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch). 
As per this link's alternative suggestion, I don't want to go with .NET Core with Linux / other OS as I don't have much knowledge on Technology/that OS too.

I am training my LUIS model using custom automation tool, so this cannot have any deployment in Azure Devops/without CI/CD.
I am not sure about Azure DevOps on how we can achieve this. If any detailed explanation about *"how we can use pipelines and add tasks which can be triggered at all times when training LUIS model with intents/utterances"* will be helpful.

**Expectation**

1. I want to train and publish the dispatcher the same way as Luis Model using API.
2. I want to refresh the Parent Luis Dipatacher Model whenever the child LUIS Model gets updated.
3. I want alternative solution/workarounds to refresh this using some API/something so that we can trigger this anytime we want to reflect changes from child LUIS models to Parent Dispatcher Model.
4. I don't know how to run the "dispatcher refresh  folderpath" command on Azure.

As we **train and publish LUIS model using API**, I need to train and Publish the Dispatcher without any manual work. Preferred Azure Workaround Solution.

Actually: Cannot automate the refresh of dispatcher using API.

Any explanation/reference to solve this problem is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your question is related to continues delivery (CI/CD). Why would you like to run the dispatcher inside a azure function? Why not doing this in a hosted build pipeline on Azure DevOps? Would you accept such an answer from me? If so, I can model a sample for this.

Comment: "Actually: Cannot automate the refresh of dispatcher using API." : why? as far as I know, dispatcher is a LUIS app like other

Comment: @SebastianZolg , If I am training and publishing a LUIS Model often and I don't require the CI/CD, because this happens without any User Interactions(so no solutions in azure devops to train and deploy everytime). If you can give me a solution from Azure Devops, to use hosted build pipeline, can it be triggerred whenever we train the child LUIS models? So that parent dispatcher will reflect the changes.

Comment: @SachinS I think I'm not fully understanding your scenario. If I understood right, you're training your model on the fly without any review/source control, directly through the API, right? Could you explain this a bit more in your question?
What about offloading all of your training process to Azure DevOps? This way you have full history and it is easy to trigger `dispatch refresh` along. Build pipelines can be triggered from your function app as well. 
Another option is [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types)

Comment: @NicolasR, As far as I tried, the Dispatcher Model can only be refreshed using CLI unlike LUIS models in windows, I haven't tried Linux or other OS using .NET Core. So I am looking for some workaround like using a.NET framework and NodeJS to form an .exe file and store in azure and then use this in Azure Function App/any other service as CLI to download Dispatcher Module and run the dispatcher refresh command. Regarding Dispatcher CLI Tool : [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch). If there is any API, let me know,I will change my question. - Thanks

Comment: @SebastianZolg, Thanks for asking, I have edited my question to explain more about the problem. And Yes I am training my LUIS model on the fly, as we have API for this unlike dispatcher model. But I don't think I can dump my training process to DevOps, I am using a custom automation tool to train utterances/intents to LUIS model, so the solution will not get changed whenever we are training, it can be thought of more like a product.  If we can still achieve this using Build pipelines as suggested, which can also be triggered from function app, Request you to please help me about achieving this

Comment: Ok, when I read your question I thought the problem was only to launch the train operation and publish operation, which can be done with the API. Here your main problem is that you also have to refresh the content of your `dispatcher` with utterances from the child apps, right?

Comment: @NicolasR, Yes Nicolas, you are right. I want to refresh the dispatcher with utterances from the child luis apps by automating, can you pls help me with this?

Comment: Did you check Azure Functions running Node? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node

Comment: @Sachin There is a bit more going on under the hood of refresh to simply run an api 'train' and 'publish' calls on LUIS (which is where dispatch lives). Trying to spin up a working sample for you.

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks for the Link, I was checking that azure functions running node and think this might be possible. If any Luck, I will update on the answer.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Its bit interesting about the dispatcher. Thanks! and let me know if you are able to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, UPDATE: We have achieved this using Azure App Service where we add Node JS Application Setting and run our .exe file to execute dispatcher CLI commands using web job. The files gets stored in the App service directory. Let me know if any other fair approach is available or if you want any details on achieving this.Thanks!

Comment: @SachinS good to hear that you made it automate. Could you please help how to do it?

Comment: @SachinS did you find any solution on this issue ? We are also stuck in the same one !!

Comment: @SachinS we also stuck here any help.

Comment: Hi, We created .dispatch file with LUIS applications initially using dispatcher CLI commands and kept the .dispatch file in Azure App Service Directory and we created a Azure Web Job(the App Service has been added with Node JS Application Setting(check the supported version in App Service)), In the Web Job, we run Process Commands which is the Dispatcher Refresh CLI commands as [link](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch). This works for dispatch file being already present in directory, but we can automate this file as well to hold newly added LUIS App.