# How to use Azure DevOps pipelines to run Refreshing of LUIS Dispatch Model

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I want to perform a "dispatch refresh" using the pipelines in Azure DevOps, however I couldn't find any reference or documentation that performs the process. I've got the idea of using the pipelines in Azure DevOps for performing "dispatch refresh" from one of the comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572615/how-do-we-automate-the-refreshing-of-luis-dispatcher-model) in StackOverflow.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: hi, is there any good news if try with the commands I provided below? Feel free to leave comment if still has any puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To able to use the `dispatch` in Azure Devops, please first use `Command line` task to execute the command:

```
npm install -g botdispatch
```

After this installed, you could run the [refresh](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#refreshing-your-dispatch-model) command:

```
dispatch refresh [options]
dispatch refresh --publishToStaging true --useAllTrainingData true
dispatch refresh --bot c:\src\bot\testbot.bot --secret <your_bot_file_secret>
```

---

If you also not to familiar with how to set CI/CD for your bot service, you can follow this blog: [Setting up a Build and Release Pipeline for Azure Bot Service using Azure DevOps](https://bisser.io/setting-up-a-build-and-release-pipeline-for-azure-bot-service-using-azure-devops/)

Since you have not provide too much details about what's your confusion, if these could not help, feel free to leave comment.